# Android + Sync Adapter + Content provider update operation failure

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

I'am using Android Sync Adapter framework to sync local DB with remote one. In onPerformSync I have an instance of (ContentProviderClient provider) which does all job with local database. To get access to the right DB I have to provide content Uri (in my case it is ServiceContract.CHECKINS_DATA_URI - content://*authority*/checkins) It works fine in query operations but when I attempt to update DB I get error:

```
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SET": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE  SET status=?,timestamp=?,user_id=?,checking_id=? WHERE timestamp = ?
```

A table name is missing between UPDATE and SET operators. It's a bit misterious because I use proper Uri. What do you think can cause this error?

public class SyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {

```
ContentResolver mContentResolver;
SvcController mController;

public SyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
    super(context, autoInitialize);

    mContentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    mController = new SvcController(context.getApplicationContext());
}

public SyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize, boolean allowParallelSyncs) {
    super(context, autoInitialize, allowParallelSyncs);

    mContentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
}

@Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account,
                          Bundle extras,
                          String authority,
                          ContentProviderClient provider,
                          SyncResult syncResult) {

    ContentValues cv;
    String[] projection;
    String selection;
    String[] selectionArgs;
    Uri uri;
```

...

```
    // updates checkin_id in local db
    uri = ServiceContract.CHECKINS_DATA_URI;
    selection = "timestamp = ?";

    for (CheckIn ci : checkins){

        cv = ci.toContentValues();
        selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ci.getTimestamp().getTime())};

        try {
            provider.update(uri, cv, selection, selectionArgs);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out what is happening. I'am new to Sync Adapter framework, so I didn't realize clearly enough how it works. The UPDATE method in sync adapter is actually an UPDATE method of regular Content provider I use to work with local database. And it wasn't tested before.